# Tabulator: How to get multiline data on separate rows

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I've an object with keys/value pair where values are comma separated in an array.
e.g.

```
var myObject = { key1 : [v11, v12, v13, v14] , key2 : [v21, v22, v23, v24]};
```

What I've working now is keys goes in as column headers and all of the array values in single row. The row data appears as comma separated.
I've a mutator that converts "," to "\n" which then converts row data and still shows in single row , albeit on different lines.

[image]

What I need is to display each value from each array on separate row , just like in excel. And also (if possible) merge rows for keys for corresponding value rows.

[image]

Here's relevant code

```
<script>
    //converts comma to newline
var customMutator = function(value, data, type, params, component){
    return value.join("\n");
}
             var tableData = [
             {id:1, key:"key1", values: ["v11", "v12", "v13", "v14"]},
             {id:1, key:"key2", values: ["v21", "v22", "v23", "v24"]},
             ];
 var table = new
Tabulator("#example-table", {
             data:tableData,
             columns:[
             {title:"key", field:"key", formatter:"textarea"},
             {title:"values",field:"values", formatter:"textarea", mutator:customMutator,},
             ],
         });
 </script>
```

Comment: Do you need to edit the data after it is loaded, or is it just for viewing purposes?

Comment: @nrayburn-tech - It is just for viewing purpose at this time. thanks.

Comment: A custom formatter would probably be the easiest thing to do then.  You would create a div with a border for each value in your array.  I will see if I can create an example for you.  What do you mean by 'merge rows for keys for corresponding value rows'?

Comment: As seen in excel example, I would like to have  one "key1" for corresponding "v11-v14". But I guess tabulator is doing that since its accommodating in single row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are only interested in viewing the data and not editing it, the easiest thing is a custom formatter.  (If you need to edit the data in that format, then I am not sure how to do that at this time.)

Your custom formatter will create an element with a border for each item in your value array.  This is an example of a custom formatter that you could use.

```
function customFormatter(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
    const val = cell.getValue();
    const cellDiv = document.createElement('div');
    for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
        const valItemDiv = document.createElement('div');
        valItemDiv.textContent = val[i];
        valItemDiv.style.border = 'purple 1px solid';
        cellDiv.appendChild(valItemDiv);
    }
    return cellDiv;
}
```

Here is a full working example.  https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/sqdvkm5u/11/

Comment: It works for the given problem, however, I noticed that it messes up pagination. I've actual data where for each  key, values can be 50+ (sometimes). Pagination in this case doesnt work as per pagination, it still count one row. For now I've pagination turned off until I figure out something else. thanks.

Comment: Well, as far as Tabulator is concerned, each `key` is one row.  I am not sure if there is a way to do row grouping, which is kind of what you are asking for.  The developer, Oli, may have some ideas or be able to offer some feedback if he sees this.

Comment: Update: Scrolling option works better in this case as opposed to pagination. So I've switched to that.